# Parsing and modifying content with Beautiful Soup (bs4)

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Goal is to modify existing html's content only.

For example, given current markup:

```html
<html lang="en" op="item">
  <head>
    <meta name="referrer" content="origin">  
    <title>The Scientific Case for Two Spaces After a Period (2018)</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <center>
        <table class="fatitem" border="0">
          <tr class='athing' id='25581282'>
            <td class="title">
              <a class="titlelink">The Scientific Case for Two Spaces After a Period (2018)</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </center>  
  </body> 
</html>
```

Suppose, I want to append `"&#x2122;"` string to each word which length is 6.

The result expected:

```html
<html lang="en" op="item">
  <head>
    <meta name="referrer" content="origin">  
    <title>The Scientific Case for Two Spaces&#x2122; After a Period&#x2122; (2018)</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <center>
        <table class="fatitem" border="0">
          <tr class='athing' id='25581282'>
            <td class="title">
              <a class="titlelink">The Scientific Case for Two Spaces&#x2122; After a Period&#x2122; (2018)</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </center>  
  </body> 
</html>
```

I'm fairly new to python, and having trouble with this. Because of nested contents, I'm struggling with properly accessing the elements and returning expected outcome.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
    soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, 'html.parser')
    new_html = []
    
    for tags in soup.contents:
        for tag in tags:
            if type(tag) != str:
                split_tag = re.split(r"(\W+)", str(tag.string))
                for word in split_tag:
                    if len(word) == 6 and  word.isalpha():
                        word += "&#x2122;"
                tag.string = "".join(split_tag)
            else:
                str_obj.append(tag)
            new_html.append(str(tag))
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried in a [mre].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.find_all(text=True)` in combination with `.replace_with()`:

```py
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<html lang="en" op="item">
  <head>
    <meta name="referrer" content="origin">  
    <title>The Scientific Case for Two Spaces After a Period (2018)</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <center>
        <table class="fatitem" border="0">
          <tr class='athing' id='25581282'>
            <td class="title">
              <a class="titlelink">The Scientific Case for Two Spaces After a Period (2018)</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </center>  
  </body> 
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")


for s in soup.find_all(text=True):
    new_s = re.sub(r"([a-zA-Z]{6,})", r"\1™", s)
    s.replace_with(new_s)

print(soup.prettify())

# to have HTML entities:
# print(soup.prettify(formatter="html"))
```

Prints:

```html
<html lang="en" op="item">
 <head>
  <meta content="origin" name="referrer"/>
  <title>
   The Scientific™ Case for Two Spaces™ After a Period™ (2018)
  </title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <center>
   <table border="0" class="fatitem">
    <tr class="athing" id="25581282">
     <td class="title">
      <a class="titlelink">
       The Scientific™ Case for Two Spaces™ After a Period™ (2018)
      </a>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </center>
 </body>
</html>
```